# Xcode objective-c error: Expected identifier

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a problem with my Xcode code.
I am getting 'Expected identifier or '('' and by looking at the other posts on this topic I've probably missed something stupid, it looks like an issue with my brackets.
This is my ViewController.m file.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController ()

@end

@implementation UIViewController

@end

@implementation AppDelegate.h {.  //I'm getting "Expected identifier or '('" here

- (IBAction)enterPassword
enterPassword.enabled = NO;

}
{
    NSString *passwordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1234"];
    if ([passwordField.text isEqualToString:passwordString]) {
        UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Correct password" message:@"This password is correct." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


} else {
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Incorrect password" message:@"This password is incorrect." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    enterPassword.delegate = self;
    enterPassword.enabled = NO;
}

}

@end
```

Thanks

EDIT:
Im getting 'Use of undeclared identifier' for my passwordField and enterPassword which are my IBOutlet and IBActions. How do I fix this? I've attached an image to show where the errors are as there is a few.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tacnz.png)

2nd EDIT:
Added self prefix
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkHmu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8nLO.png)

Comment: change that row to @implementation AppDelegate {

Comment: Regarding the edit: You'll want to prefix those outlets/actions with self: `self.enterPassword`

Comment: Thank you raidfive, how do you do that exactly? Ive tried self.enterPassword and just self enterPassword but these are both returning more errors...

Answer (score -1):

You don't need braces around the bits between the `@implementation` and `@end`.   Those keywords define the scope of the class's implementation completely.   Actually, there are a bunch of syntax errors throughout that.

Also, the re-declaration of the UIViewController class is going to cause an error, too.  You don't need to declare that at all;  the import of UIKit will find it.

This is closer (but I didn't try compiling it, either):

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (IBAction)enterPassword
{

enterPassword.enabled = NO;

    NSString *passwordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1234"];
    if ([passwordField.text isEqualToString:passwordString]) {
        UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Correct password" message:@"This password is correct." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


} else {
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Incorrect password" message:@"This password is incorrect." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    enterPassword.delegate = self;
    enterPassword.enabled = NO;
}
}    
@end
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting a different error now though :( see edit for details

Comment: @WillHampshire Those are some very basic syntax errors.   I would suggest you spend some time with an Objective-C tutorial before continuing.

Comment: Could you suggest a free one please? I've had a look on google but some of them look a bit rubbish.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-11-apps-with-swift/id1309275316 though swift.   Big Nerd Ranch has excellent stuff.  I've always started with Apple's tutorials and docs, though.